# How to display image through URL in angular from web api project directory

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am getting image from angular and save it in a folder named Image in web API directory and name of the image is saved in database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW6cn.png)
here is the code for image upload.

```
public HttpResponseMessage uploadImage()
        {
            try
            {
                string image = null;
                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                //upload image
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files["Image"];
                image = new string(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(" ", "-");
                image = image + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image/" + image);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
                {
                    EmployeeImage ei = new EmployeeImage()
                    {
                        image = image,
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(httpRequest["ID"])
                    };
                    entities.EmployeeImages.Add(ei);
                    entities.SaveChanges();

                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,ex);
            }
        }
```

and on getImage I am return image URL and image ID.
here is the code for getImage

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage()
        {
            try
            {
                var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
                string filePath = url.Scheme + "://" + url.Host + ":" + url.Port + "/Image/";
                using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
                {
                    var entity = entities.EmployeeImages.ToList<EmployeeImage>();
                    for (int t = 0; t < entity.Count(); t++)
                    {
                        entity[t].image= filePath + entity[t].image;
                    }
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            }
        }
```

and in angluar service i am getting this like this.

```
public getFiles(): Observable < any[] > {  
    return this.http.get < any[] > (this.uri + 'employeeimage/getImage',{headers: new HttpHeaders(
      {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('userToken')})});
  }
```

and then call this method in component-name.component.ts file

```
lstFile : EmployeePic[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.lstFile={} as EmployeePic[];
    this.service.getFiles().subscribe(result => {  
      this.lstFile = result as EmployeePic[];  
    })
```

and then when i call it in html file like this

```
<img class="rounded-circle" [src]="lstFile[i].image" height="60" width="60">
```

then it gives error like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8I21.png)

also when i am trying to put the image URL in browser then 404 not found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFl4s.png)
here is the code for my startup.cs file

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(webApi.Startup))]

namespace webApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions option = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                Provider = new applicationOauthProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                AllowInsecureHttp = false
            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(option);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: copy the path of error in browser and check if you can access the image. As far as I know you  need to to convert the image into bytes and send with http response and the on angular side you need to convert byte array into image again.

Comment: no i could not acces image in browser

Comment: Then you can not access from web application. Try to convert it into bytes and then in angular typescript convert again from bytes to image.